# Angular.js update scope after variable has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a search-bar in my web page, which is associated with a controller that receives a JSON object as a response from the server.

I then save this response in a global variable named `assetResult`.

It works fine the first time but when I do a new search the `$scope` of `searchResultController` is not updated

CONTROLLER SEARCH BAR

```
mwm3.controller('searchBarCtrl', function($scope, $location, $timeout, AssetService) {
        $scope.radioValue = 'id';
        AssetService.connect();
        AssetService.subscribe(function(message) {
            var obj;
            try {
                //$scope.ocw.push(message);
                obj = eval("(function(){return " + message + ";})()");
                AssetResult = obj;
                console.log(message);

                $location.url('/searchResult');
            } catch (e) {
                obj = eval("(function(){return " + message + ";})()");
                alert(obj.Error);
            }
            //$route.reload();

        });

        $scope.send = function() {
            AssetService.send($scope.radioValue + '=' + $scope.searchKey);

        };

    });
```

CONTROLLER SEARCH RESULT

```
mwm3.controller('searchResultCtrl', function($scope, $location, AssetDetailService) {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.asm = AssetResult;
    });

    if (!AssetResult) {
        $location.url('/login');
    }
});
```

I use `$scope.apply` in my `searchResultController` but the associated view is not refreshed anyway.

Where is my problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `eval("(function(){return " + message + ";})()")`? Why not just `function(){return " + message + ";})()`?

Comment: thanks for it but this don't solve my problem.

Comment: @dfsq or even shorter `obj = message`. There is no need for a self invoking function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me, as if the message from the `AssetService` does not start a new angular digest. Try in your `searchBarCtrl`:

```
AssetResult = obj;
$scope.$apply();
```

Comment: Yep, use $scope.$apply() to notify angular when something from outside updates and $scope.$watch() to notify code outside of angular. That way you can manage state between angular and external code.

Comment: thanks doup. I add scope.applay() in my searchBarCtrl and scope.watch() in my searchResultCtrl. It's work for me